# Amazon S3: How to automatically copy uploaded files to another directory upon file creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket where files are uploaded regularly, with the folowing directory structure:

```
backup/
process/
```

The ideia is: I upload files to `backup`, the new files are regularly copied to `process` where they are processed by a third-party service that read and remove these files.

So in the end `backup` would have all the uploaded files, while `process` would only have the new uploaded files while they weren't processed by the third-party service.

How can I regularly (and automatically) copy these new files from `backup` to `process` without using stuff like lambda?

I found a S3 replication feature, but it only seems to copy objects from a bucket to another.

Are there some kind of event that constantly reads the directory, and when new files are created they are copied to the `process` directory?

Comment: Why not just use another bucket and bucket replication? If it needs to be same bucket then a simple lambda function can do this.

Comment: why not lambda?